# How to start a plist agent running as root at boot

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl

I have installed nginx via homebrew, by default it provides a plist which is symlinked from `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and running `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/nginx.plist` starts nginx as my user account.

I want nginx to be able to listen on port 443 to test some HTTPS stuff. So this means running nginx as root. By placing the plist file in `/Library/LaunchAgents` insetad I can run `sudo launchctl load ...` and nginx starts and everything runs correctly.

However, in this scenario nginx isn’t started at boot time. I must manually start nginx after every reboot.

Is it possible to have launchctl start nginx as root at bootup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agents are loaded when logging in, daemons when booting. Agents are run on behalf of the user being logged in, daemons are run on behalf of root or the user/group specified by the `UserName`/`GroupName` key.

Move your job definition to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and you should be fine.